# Calculate the measure of the arc A in the circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Twice the measure of the arc $\overline{AB}$ is equal to the measure of the arc $ASB$ and $\overline{KL}=1$. If $\overline{KB}$ is an integer value, calculate the measure of the arc $AB$. (Answer: $120^\circ$)

[image]

Here's the information I managed to find...through geogebra, the only way to get to the template is when the center of one circle is in the other and both have the same radius

$\dfrac{\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{AB}-\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{LR}}{2}$

$\angle K =\dfrac{\angle BOA}{2}$

$\overline{KL}\cdot\overline{KA} = \overline{KR}\cdot\overline{RB}\implies \overline{KA}=\overline{KR}\cdot\overline{KB}$

[image]